# JPA. Deleting a parent cause Foreigconstraint violation exception

Tags: java, jpa

Deleting a **customer** results in the following exception

```
CustomerDTO customerDTO = customerDAO.findById(9);
customerDAO.remove(customerDTO);
```

**"Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"**

I am using **CascadeType.ALL** and **orphanRemoval=true** on my relations, but it is not working.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class CustomerDTO implements Serializable {

@Column(name = "cust_first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "cust_last_name")
private String lastName;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="customerDTO", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<SystemContractDTO> lstDeviceContractsDTO;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "SYSTEM_CONTRACT")
public class SystemContractDTO implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
    private CustomerDTO customerDTO;

}
```